# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in a simple C code due to large range of values the variable takes

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have written the following code to find the largest palindrome formed by the product of 3-digit numbers. There is a problem with the nested loops which is giving the segmentation fault. Can someone help me with the debugging?

The code works fine for smaller numbers but gives segmentation fault for larger numbers (which is the reason I took long int instead of int for k, l, max and a variables).

```
#include<stdio.h>
long reverse(long);
main()
{
long k, l, max, a[100];
int i, j, t=0;
printf("hello\n");
for(i=999; i>99; i--)
{
    for(j=999; j>99;j--)
    {
    //  printf("hello\n");          
        k=i*j;
        l= reverse(k);
        if(k==l) {a[t]=k; t++; }
    }
}
printf("hello\n");
max=a[0];
for(t=1;t<100; t++)
{
    if(max<a[t]) {max=a[t];}
}
printf("Largest palindrome is %ld\n", max);
}


long reverse(long n)
{
long rev=0;
while(n!=0)
{
    rev= rev*10;
    rev= rev+n%10;
    n=n/10; 
}
return rev;
}
```

Comment: What happens when `t>=100`? Are you sure you allocated enough space in the `a[]` array?

Comment: There are 2470 palindromes in the searched number space. `a`, with its 100 elements, is simply too small to hold them all. Hint: If you're only trying to find the largest, you do not have to remember them all.

Answer (score 1):

For large numbers, `t` increases beyond the size of the array `a`.

This will cause the program to write on the program stack where it shouldn't which can cause a crash with a core dump.

If you only want to find the largest palindrome, you don't to save them all. You can just save the largest one.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `a` is only 100 elements long, you need to ensure `t` is always less than 100 or you will overflow the bounds of your array.  You might want to use `realloc` to dynamically allocate `a` using a pointer.